# Tcl 'wrong # args: extra words after "else" clause in "if" command'

Tags: if-statement, tcl

I searched for similar threads involving this error related to the use of "elseif" and double checked to make sure I wasn't making any of the same mistakes that were previously posted or discussed. Based on my research, I believe this code is accurate and formatted properly. Could there be a version issue and perhaps my company doesn't have the correct libraries or did I truly mess up the syntax?

The Error I'm receiving is:

```
[0:TEST] Tcl error:
    msgId   = message0
    proc    = 'X_EPIC_UROLOGY_OBR_xlate'
    args    = ''
    result  = 'wrong # args: extra words after "else" clause in "if" command'
    errorInfo: '
wrong # args: extra words after "else" clause in "if" command
    while executing
"if { [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $att_prov] == 1} {
                    set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $a..."
invoked from within
"if [cequal $segtype PV1] {

                  set fieldList [split $seg $field_sep]

                  if { [regexp {1184684789|189175..."
    (procedure "X_EPIC_UROLOGY_OBR_xlate" line 166)
    invoked from within
"X_EPIC_UROLOGY_OBR_xlate {MSGID message0} {CONTEXT sms_ib_data} {ARGS {}} {MODE run} {VERSION 3.0}"'
```

My Code:

```
              if [cequal $segtype PV1] {

              set fieldList [split $seg $field_sep]

                 if { [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $att_prov] == 1} {
                  set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $att_prov]
                 } elseif {
                [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $ord_prov_obr] == 1} {
                    set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $ord_prov_obr] 
                 } elseif {
                [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $cc_prov] == 1} {
                    set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $cc_prov] 
                 } elseif {
                [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $ord_prov_orc] == 1} {
                    set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $ord_prov_orc]
                 } elseif {
                [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $ref_prov] == 1} {
                    set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $ref_prov]
                 }  else {
                [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $cc_prov] == 1} {
                    set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $cc_prov]
                 }
              }
```

Comment: Please don't include pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Post updated.

Comment: I wouldn't really advise using those checks with regexp. You can easily use `$att_prov in {1184684789 1891756748 1356301840 1457541278 1275755076}` which will be faster and work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your last "else". you have two "words" after it.

The way tcl see it is this:

```
} else { [regexp ...] == 1} {...}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^
       word 1               word 2
```

The "extra word after else clause" is word 2, the `{...}` part. After the `else` you're only allowed to have a single "word" (tcl's definition of "word", not a literal word").

If this is truly an "else" (ie: do this if all of the other conditions fail"), you need to just remove all of word 1. If it's another condition, you need to change `else` to `elseif` so that it treats word 1 as an expression.

Comment: You rock, I'm new to tcl so I greatly appreciate that explanation and it works perfectly now that I've altered it based on your solution. I know this isn't ground breaking stuff I'm doing so thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
}  else {
  [regexp {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076} $cc_prov] == 1} {
     set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $cc_prov]
}
```

This should be an `elseif`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I ended up doing based on Bryan's comment.

Answer (score -1):

You have the answer to your syntax error. Now, a bit of code review.

You have a lot of cut'n'paste code in there. DRY:

```
if {[cequal $segtype PV1]} {
#  ^.....................^ remember to brace the expression

    set fieldList [split $seg $field_sep]
    set pattern {1184684789|1891756748|1356301840|1457541278|1275755076}
    foreach word [list $att_prov $ord_prov_obr $cc_prov $ord_prov_orc $ref_prov $cc_prov] {
        if {[regexp $pattern $word]} {
            set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $word]
            break
        }
    }
}
```

It appears with the regexp command that you are validating that a word is in an allowed list of words. You don't want to get false positives, for example in case $att_prov equals "118". I'd take the regexp out of it, and just test for list membership which uses string equality

```
    set allowed {1184684789 1891756748 1356301840 1457541278 1275755076}
    foreach word [list $att_prov $ord_prov_obr $cc_prov $ord_prov_orc $ref_prov $cc_prov] {
        if {$word in $allowed} {
            set fieldList [lreplace $fieldList 7 7 $word]
            break
        }
    }
```

Aside from choosing  variable names that suit your domain better, I think this more clearly expresses your intent.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I hadn't considered that route and it does appear significantly cleaner. In regards to the variable naming conventions, I have to use a method the more senior guys like (I don't like them either).

Comment: I was referring to *my* variable names "allowed", "word", "pattern". You might want to alter those.